# Algo inusual ha ocurrido que provocó un fallo en el controlador

Tags: android-studio, postgresql, kotlin

Estoy intentando una conexión de kotlin y postgresql pero de alguna manera la conexión me retorna nula.

Quiero hacer una conexión directa desde kotlin y postgresql14

MainActivity:

```
val base:Modelo= Modelo()
base.listar()
```

Modelo.kt

```
fun connect(): Connection? {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, clave)
        } catch (e: SQLException) {
            println("-----$e")
        }
        return conn
    }

fun cerrarConexion(connection: Connection){
        conn!!.close();
    }


fun listar(): String {
        val statement: Statement?
        val resultSet:ResultSet?
        var cedula:String=""
        try{
            statement=connect()!!.createStatement()
            resultSet=statement.executeQuery("Select * from usuarios")
            while (resultSet.next()){
                cedula+=resultSet.getString("cedula")+", "
                println("-----------$cedula")
            }
        }catch (e:SQLException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return cedula
    }
```

Este es el error que me sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice una función main para ejecutar en Android Studio la misma función listar y si me salen resultados, algo cambia cuando lo ejecuto como aplicación?.

```
fun main(){
    val base: Modelo = Modelo()
    base.listar()
}
```

Comment: Ese amigo `conn` puede viajar nulo si no logras conectarte y le estás corriendo el método createStatement sin pena ni gloria.

Comment: Pero en el archivo de prueba si me sale la conexion y me retorna el resultado

Comment: Será que al preparar la app, no incluyes el driver "entre las dependencias" (el classpath, pues) y no está disponible? No sé, mi kung fu en kotlin es mínimo...

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un archivo llammado prueba.kt y retorna el resultado

Tiene el metodo:

```
fun main(){
    val base: Modelo = Modelo()
    base.listar()
}
```

y retorna:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]